# How can I convert to Swift async/await from GCD (DispatchQueue)?

Tags: swift, async-await, grand-central-dispatch

I am following Stanfords' CS193p Developing Apps for iOS online course.

It is using the Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) API for a demo of multithreading.
But they noted, that

> "GCD has been mostly replaced by Swift's new built-in async API as of WWDC 2021".

So I wanted to learn how the code from the Lecture would look like after updating it to use this new API.

After watching Apple's WWDC videos, it seems to me like
`DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { }` is replaced in this new async API with `Task { }` or `Task(priority: .userInitiated) {}`, but I'm not sure, what has `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` been replaced with?

***So, my questions are:***

1. Am I correctly assuming, that `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { }` has been replaced with `Task(priority: .userInitiated) {}`
2. What has `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` been replaced with?

Please help, I want to learn this new async-await API.

Here's the code from the Lecture, using old GCD API:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        if self?.emojiArt.background == EmojiArtModel.Background.url(url) {
            self?.backgroundImageFetchStatus = .idle
            if imageData != nil {
                self?.backgroundImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            }
            // L12 note failure if we couldn't load background image
            if self?.backgroundImage == nil {
                self?.backgroundImageFetchStatus = .failed(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The whole function (in case you need to see more code):

```swift
private func fetchBackgroundImageDataIfNecessary() {
    backgroundImage = nil
    switch emojiArt.background {
    case .url(let url):
        // fetch the url
        backgroundImageFetchStatus = .fetching
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                if self?.emojiArt.background == EmojiArtModel.Background.url(url) {
                    self?.backgroundImageFetchStatus = .idle
                    if imageData != nil {
                        self?.backgroundImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    }
                    // L12 note failure if we couldn't load background image
                    if self?.backgroundImage == nil {
                        self?.backgroundImageFetchStatus = .failed(url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    case .imageData(let data):
        backgroundImage = UIImage(data: data)
    case .blank:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely shouldn't have been using `.userInteractive` for `Data(contentsOf: url)` in your original code. Instead, look at the asynchronous URL methods like using `URLSession`. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui

Comment: Or leave async/await for now if you are a beginner programmer. Besides, you are asking us to do all the work for you here which isn’t how it is supposed to be.

Comment: You are right, it was `.userInitiated`, not `.userInteractive` in the Lecture. I will update the question.

Comment: And you are right, that using `URLSession' is a better way to do this, but the Stanford professor was temporarily using GCD instead to **explain** multithreading. A few lectures later he changed that to `URLSession`

Comment: And I am not asking you to do all the work.
I am asking:
1. Am I correctly assuming, that `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { }` has been replaced with `Task(priority: .userInitiated) {}`
2. What has DispatchQueue.main.async { } been replaced with?

Comment: I will update the question to make it more clear what I am asking about.

Comment: Please see [this detailed article](https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-5-replacing-gcd-with-async-await/)

Comment: Thank you vadian!
I have read this article, but didn't found the answer. I will keep searching the answer to my first question, if anyone can add something, that could help me, I would appreciate.
Oh, and am I right by thinking I can replace `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { }` with `Task(priority: .userInitiated) {}`?

Comment: [This article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/25013447-async-await-in-swiftui) might be better. It explains async/await in conjunction with URLSession and SwiftUI.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you really are going to do something slow and synchronous, `Task.detached` is a closer analog to GCD’s dispatching to a global queue. If you just use `Task(priority: ...) { ... }` you are leaving it to the discretion of the concurrency system to decide which thread to run it on. (And just because you specify a lower `priority` does not guarantee that it might not run on the main thread.)

For example:

```swift
func fetchAndUpdateUI(from url: URL) {
    Task.detached {                          // or specify a priority with `Task.detached(priority: .background)`
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        await self.updateUI(with: image)
    }
}
```

And if you want to do the UI update on the main thread, rather than dispatching it back to the main queue, you would simply add the `@MainActor` modifier to the method that updates the UI:

```swift
@MainActor
func updateUI(with image: UIImage?) async {
    imageView.image = image
}
```

That having been said, this is a pretty unusual pattern (doing the network request synchronously and creating a detached task to make sure you don't block the main thread). We would probably use `URLSession`’s new asynchronous [`data(from:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767353-data) method to perform the request asynchronously. It offers better error handling, greater configurability, participates in structured concurrency, and is cancelable.

In short, rather than looking for one-to-one analogs for the old GCD patterns, use the concurrent API that Apple has provided where possible.

---

FWIW, in addition to the `@MainActor` pattern shown above (as a replacement for dispatching to the main queue), you can also do:

```swift
await MainActor.run {
    …
}
```

That is roughly analogous to the dispatching to the main queue. In WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194?time=1290), they say:

> In Swift’s concurrency model, there is a global actor called the main actor that coordinates all operations on the main thread. We can replace our `DispatchQueue.main.async` with a call to `MainActor`’s `run` function. This takes a block of code to run on the `MainActor`. …

But he goes on to say:

> I can annotate functions with `@MainActor`. And that will require that the caller switch to the main actor before this function is run. … Now that we've put this function on the main actor, we don’t, strictly speaking, need this `MainActor.run` anymore.

Comment: What if you want to do something in the background thread and then finish up with result in main, which would have nothing todo with `URLSession`? **user14119170** question is really reasonable, because `DispatchQueue` was indeed used for such cases as well. Therefore, what's the right way to do a background thread with async/await concurrency outside `URLSession` examples?

Comment: As I outlined above, a detached task is the simplest way to run some computationally intensive task on background thread. (You can also do it with actors.) My point re `URLSession` was merely that the OP’s example of synchronous network request is a poor use-case.