# Retain cycles with MainActor and async/await

Tags: swift, async-await

I was trying to understand how to use `Task` in Swift. So I have a few related questions

From reading online I found that you don't need to use `weak self` inside a `Task` as long as you are **sure** that the `Task` will end. But wasn't that the case with `DispatchQueues` too? For example if you make a network call

```
Task {
   try? await self.doNetworkCall()
}
```

1. You could replace `Task` with `DispatchQueue` and it would have no effect. Correct?
2. Are there any cases that would result in the `Task` not completing? Apart from the developer *intentionally* blocking the queue. Like anything apart from a `Thread.sleep` or something? Maybe a case of an API failure somehow?
3. Are there any differences between `MainActor.run`, `ImmediateScheduler.schedule` and `DispatchQueue.main.async`? Specifically in the context of the example above to perform updates on the UI from inside the `Task`. I don't mean anything like one is in the Combine library etc.

Comment: `MainActor.run`, `ImmediateScheduler.schedule` and `DispatchQueue.main.async` are not interchangeable. Floating `Task {}` are bad practice you should always hang on to the task and `cancel` when not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> I found that you don't need to use `weak self` inside a `Task` as long as you are sure that the `Task` will end.

Yes, one frequently doesn’t need to use `[weak self]` capture list if one knows that this temporary strong reference will eventually be released.

(It should be recognized that avoidance of strong reference cycles is not the only reason one might use a `weak` reference. But it is beyond the scope of the question to go through all of these edge cases.)

But, this begs the more important question: Do you need/want this asynchronous task to continue when you no longer need `self`? Often, no, we don’t. Specifically, we often want to cancel a `Task` when its results are no longer needed. And if you cancel tasks when they are no longer needed, the `weak` references become largely moot.

Now, in SwiftUI, the [`.task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier takes care of this for us because “SwiftUI will automatically cancel the task at some point after the view disappears before the action completes.”

E.g.:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack { … }
        .task {
            await doNetworkCall()
        }
    }
    
    func doNetworkCall() async { … }
}
```

When the `ContentView` is dismissed, `doNetworkCall` will be canceled. (And because of *structured concurrency,* the `URLSession.shared.data(from:delegate:)` (or whatever) inside that method will automatically be canceled, too.) And when the task finishes, any implicit strong references are resolved, too. No strong reference cycle.

Now, when doing this with `Task {…}` (which is *unstructured concurrency*), the burden for cancelation falls on our shoulders. So we simply hang on to that `Task` and manually cancel it later (e.g., in UIKit or AppKit, we might start the task in `viewDidAppear` and cancel it, if it is not already done, in `viewDidDisappear`):

```swift
var task: Task<Void, Error>?

func start() {
    task = Task {
        try await doNetworkCall()
    }
}

func cancel() {
    task?.cancel()
}
```

You go on to ask:

> But wasn't that the case with `DispatchQueue`s too?

Yes, the strong reference cycle with `DispatchQueue` was not a concern unless you kept a persistent strong reference to `self` without any way to resolve it. (Traditionally, the way strong references are introduced with closures is if the called function saves the closure to some variable and neglects to `nil` it when done.)

But if you did `queue.async {…}` with a reference to `self` in the closure, it would keep a strong reference to `self` until the closure finished, at which point it would remove its strong reference. But at the same time, unless you added some special logic, it would keep running the lengthy asynchronous process running (and keep `self` in memory) well after `self` was no longer needed.

> 1. You could replace `Task` with `DispatchQueue` and it would have no effect. Correct?

Yes, `DispatchQueue` method `async`, it will remove its strong reference to `self` as soon as execution finishes, thereby avoiding strong reference cycles (as long as this closure was not saved in a variable and was neglected to be `nil`ed).

But with dispatch queue’s `async`, many developers would blithely ignore the cancelation flow. (In our defense, GCD is a bit clumsy re cancelation. `Operation` handles cancelation far more gracefully, but it quickly got hairy when wrapping asynchronous processes. “Swift concurrency”, especially structured concurrency, handles cancelation far more gracefully.)

> 2. Are there any cases that would result in the `Task` not completing? Apart from the developer intentionally blocking the queue. Like anything apart from a Thread.sleep or something? Maybe a case of an API failure somehow?

No, you would really have to go out of your way to create a `Task` that does not complete in a reasonable amount of time. E.g., a simple network request generally finishes within a reasonable amount of time (or simply times out).

But we sometimes explicitly create tasks that never finish. E.g., a task with a `for`-`await`-`in` for some [`notifications`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/3813137-notifications) sequence will continue to run unless explicitly canceled. But that is OK, as we do not want it to end until we explicitly cancel it. (The details here do not matter, but the answer is that some asynchronous tasks are designed to run until canceled.)

Regardless, to repeat, we generally ensure that our tasks are cancelable. (Fortunately, most of the Apple `async` API are cancelable.) If we factor in cancelation, then the “how long before the task finishes” becomes moot.

> 3. Are there any differences between MainActor.run, ImmediateScheduler.schedule and DispatchQueue.main.async? Specifically in the context of the example above to perform updates on the UI from inside the Task. I don't mean anything like one is in the Combine library etc.

There are tons of differences, but that’s really off topic. If your question is whether there is some reason why, when using Swift concurrency, that you wouldn’t just use the main actor for UI updates, the answer is no, not really. You probably should pick a tech stack and stick with it. If using Swift concurrency, use the main actor. If using GCD, use `DispatchQueue.main`. Etc. But you really do not want to be jumping between the various approaches.

---

As an aside, you reference `MainActor.run {…}`. That is a bit of a special API that is overused in answers that you see here on Stack Overflow. For those coming from GCD, it feels like an appealing and intuitive alternative to `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}`. But applying this sort of GCD pattern to your Swift concurrency codebase is only inheriting the same brittle issues we had with GCD.

The best practice is to mark methods, properties, and types that need the main actor with the `@MainActor` qualifier, and *not* use `MainActor.run {…}`. Back in GCD days, the burden was often placed on the caller to make sure it called a method from the main thread, but nowadays, we decorate the called method accordingly, and the compiler will ensure we call it properly (from asynchronous contexts, at least). Relying solely on `MainActor.run {…}` can be a bit fragile, where you, the developer, has to remember to `run` it on the main actor. It’s better to have compile-time warnings about misuse, rather than placing that burden on the developer or the runtime main thread checker. There are special cases where we use `MainActor.run {…}`, but not as a simple one-for-one replacement of old GCD patterns.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70070581/1271826) for some excerpts from WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194?time=1290) which talks about how you *can* use `MainActor.run {…}`, but that you might alternatively decorate with `@MainActor`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and tip about `MainActor.run`. I was indeed using it as an alternative to `DispatchQueue.main.async` :)